# We found an issue in the following area(s): SPLIT_BUNDLE 74, App get rejected. What is the solution?

Tags: android, flutter

My app has functionality that finds labs where users can book lab appointments, And having Covid 19 labs where users can book covid 19 appointments. The app gets rejected due to a violation of policy. Can someone tell me what is the exact issue?

Here the reply from Google -
Images from READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
Images from WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 74
About the Google Play developer requirements for coronavirus disease 2019 (COVID-19)

[Email Attachement from Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIQQh.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.